# R aborted when using install_keras(tensorflow="gpu")

Tags: r, keras

I'm trying keras in R. I tried the below code as Chollet's book. 
Cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.4.2 are installed.

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(tensorflow="gpu")
imdb<-dataset_imdb(num_words = 10000)
```

But it gives the error message(R session aborted, R encounters a fatal error. The session was terminated)  and I have to restart R
It happens to any code.

However if I alter the augment of tensorflow to 1.4, it works.

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
install_keras(tensorflow="1.4")
imdb<-dataset_imdb(num_words = 10000)
```

What should I do, to solve this termination phenomenon?
Why does this termination occur only when option is gpu.
Thanks in advance.